# How to prevent black holes when baking diffuse colors?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, baking

I am trying to bake a high poly model onto a low poly model I created using [Instant Meshes](https://github.com/wjakob/instant-meshes). However, when baking the diffuse colors I get a lot artifacts (black holes under the chin and in the eyes):

[image]

**Q:** How can I bake the diffuse colors onto the low poly model in a clean fashion?

Comment: Try to increase the ray distance and/or shrinkwrap the low poly onto the high poly version.

Comment: Adding a shrinkwrap modifier helped a lot. thanks! I have a second question: What does the option extrude stand for? Can I use it to get a better result?

Answer (score 0):

blender newer than 2.8
black holes / black spots while baking a cavity map

For those, who follow the udemy "Blender Character Creator for Video Games design", section "bake the orcs cavity map":

use Extrusion 0.01 and max ray distance 0.04 for example.